# How can I check an answer then Load a new one

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to make a quiz that reads from a random file, checks the answer then picks a new question. I am having trouble because when I click the button to check the answer it checks it against the next question instead of the current. I think this has something to do with opening the next question before checking. I am only fairly new to Visual Basic and coding in general so any help will be appreciated.
Here is the code giving me the trouble.(Sorry for the big chunk of Code)

```
Private Sub btn_next_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btn_next.Click

    ProgressBar1.Increment(1)

    'Selects Random Number and Puts it into var_qnum
    Dim curNumber As Integer
    If (alreadyPicked.Count < var_amount) Then
        Dim rand As Random = New Random
        Do
            curNumber = rand.Next(0, var_amount)
        Loop While (alreadyPicked.Contains(curNumber))
    End If

    If (curNumber >= 0 AndAlso Not alreadyPicked.Contains(curNumber)) Then
        alreadyPicked.Add(curNumber)
        var_qnum = curNumber
        var_filepath = "\questions\" + var_qnum.ToString + ".txt"
    Else

    End If
        'Defines var_row stuff
        Dim var_row As Integer = 0
        Dim var_question As String
        Dim var_type As String
        Dim var_answer As String
        Dim var_opta As String
        Dim var_optb As String
        Dim var_optc As String
        Dim var_optd As String

    'Opens the file corresponding to var_qnum
    Using MyReader As New Microsoft.VisualBasic.
        FileIO.TextFieldParser(
          Application.StartupPath & var_filepath)
        MyReader.TextFieldType = FileIO.FieldType.Delimited
        MyReader.SetDelimiters("|")
        Dim currentRow As String()
        While Not MyReader.EndOfData
            Try
                currentRow = MyReader.ReadFields()
                Dim currentField As String
                For Each currentField In currentRow
                    var_row += 1
                    If var_row = 1 Then
                        var_question = currentField
                    ElseIf var_row = 2 Then
                        var_type = currentField
                    ElseIf var_row = 3 Then
                        var_opta = currentField
                    ElseIf var_row = 4 Then
                        var_optb = currentField
                    ElseIf var_row = 5 Then
                        var_optc = currentField
                    ElseIf var_row = 6 Then
                        var_optd = currentField
                    ElseIf var_row = 7 Then
                        var_answer = currentField
                        var_row = 0
                    ElseIf var_row = 3 And var_type = "Close" Then
                        var_answer = currentField
                        var_row = 0
                    End If
                Next
            Catch ex As Microsoft.VisualBasic.
          FileIO.MalformedLineException
                MsgBox("Line " & ex.Message &
"Is Not valid And will be skipped.")
            End Try
        End While
    End Using

    lbl_type.Text = var_type
    If var_type = "Multiple Choice" Then
        rb_a.Visible = True
        rb_b.Visible = True
        rb_c.Visible = True
        rb_d.Visible = True
        rb_a.Text = var_opta
        rb_b.Text = var_optb
        rb_c.Text = var_optc
        rb_d.Text = var_optd
    End If

    lbl_number.Text = var_qnum.ToString
    txt_questionbox.Text = var_question

    Dim var_check As String = "NULL"
    If rb_a.Checked Then
        var_check = "a"
    ElseIf rb_b.Checked Then
        var_check = "b"
    ElseIf rb_c.Checked Then
        var_check = "c"
    ElseIf rb_d.Checked Then
        var_check = "d"
    End If

    If var_check = var_answer Then
        var_correct += 1
        rb_a.Checked = False
        rb_b.Checked = False
        rb_c.Checked = False
        rb_d.Checked = False
        btn_next.Text = "Skip"
        var_check = "NULL"
    ElseIf var_check = "NULL" Then
        var_skip += 1
    ElseIf var_check <> var_answer Then

        var_incorrect += 1
        rb_a.Checked = False
        rb_b.Checked = False
        rb_c.Checked = False
        rb_d.Checked = False
        btn_next.Text = "Skip"
        var_check = "NULL"
    Else
        MsgBox("Error")
    End If

    If var_correct + var_incorrect + var_skip = var_amount Then
        Me.Visible = False
        Form3.Visible = True
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: `I think this has something to do with opening the next question before checking.`
Indeed, you are assigning a new value to var_qnum, and therefore you are opening the next file; and afterwards, you are checking the "old" question with the next file.
It should probably work, if you do the answer check first, then move on to the next question

Comment: I did try to do that but then when it checks against the answer it marks it as wrong, as the answer is blank

Comment: Did you go through your code using the debugger yet? That's usually the best you can do. Since I don't know how you assign answers or how your quiz works in general, it's pretty hard to to give more precise advice.

However, the cycle should look somewhat like this:
1. Assign current question
2. Let user pick his answer
3. Check answer with question you assigned at 1.
4. Go back to 1, assign new current question